# Нейминг и архитектура в django

Tags: django, code-style

Хочется найти фундаментальные материалы, возможно книги, по организации архитектуры проектов с django и впринципе python. Существует множество статей которые рассматривают кодстайл в каких-либо локальных моментах, та же самая документация и PEP (например https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/). Но хочется посмотреть какой-либо фундаментальный набор советов и примеров по этой теме. Смотря просто рандомные репозитории не дают уверенности. Надеюсь на ваше понимание.